# How to validate two or more separate records (different models) in one action in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, devise

I have a custom Devise create action that creates the User but also creates a bunch of other records in other models on User signup so that the User has some tools available the second they signup. I have this all working using the usual User signup form that Devise auto-generates and also an extra text_field_tag field which gives the name for a Group which is auto-created for the User on signup. First problem is I want to run all validations to ensure the Group and User fields are valid before any records get saved. Currently the User gets created and if that works the Group gets created along with the necessary joins. I need to ensure the Group name is valid before saving the User. Should I just include the Active Record validations module in the controller and use a before_action?

Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Devise part you can use the `Active Record callbacks` you can create a method on the `User model` to verify the validity the `group_name`. Or you can just use `Active Record Validation module` on your `model` and if the record not valid the use will not going to be saved and list of errors will be rendered, `devise` depends on `ActiveRecord`.

Comment: This issue is it needs to check validation in the controller before the model is even engaged. The group name is of the model Group not User.

Comment: you said you have a custom `devise create action`. Why don't you customize it even further and run any necessary validation you want. For instance when you create a new group you should have validate for uniqueness on the `Group model` and if a new group gets created successfully you just continue creating the user and if the not you render the errors, perhaps if you could show us the customized create method I could help you further

Comment: I could do that but I want to avoid hitting the database unnecessarily. In your example if the Group gets created and then the User validations fail then I have to delete the Group again. That is two database actions that could be avoided.

Comment: if you build your validation on the models, then you can check first if the Group is valid if it is true check if the user is valid as well, then if both return true you can smoothly save both of them. There is an instance method called `valid?` comes from `ActiveRecord::Validations `

Comment: Ok, I think I got you. I do something like `Group.build( name: params[:group_name]).valid?` and if it passes do the same for user!?

Comment: Yes, exactly `validate` both `group object` and `user object` before save. if both return true then continue with save if any of them return error, extract the errors and render back the registration form with errors that have occured

Comment: Awesome thanks. Any ideas on the rspec side of things?.. If not I'll break it out into a new question.

Comment: you had better break it into another question or wait for someone else to give you an answer for it.